# SQL Server can't find any services run

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssms

I have *MS SQL Server v 17.3*
I am always using the engine to connect with external servers 
but the problem starts when I tried to connect to the Local server with the machine name `.` and using the windows authentication which gives me the error of :

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to ..

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

first I think the problem with the name of an instance so I tried to get it from configuration management so I went to the services to get the name of the instance from running services, but I find that there are no services running except the `VSS Writer` as the attached image :

[image]

then I went to the configuration manager where I find that there is no services as the attached image :
[image]

I went to repair the installation but the result is the same:
*No services running for SQL Server
*I can't Connect to Local server

**Note that the SQL server engine can connect to other servers successfully.**

when I went to this path :

[C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMicrosoft%20SQL%20Server)

I find that there are many folders here like attached image :
[image]

So I don't know what is the problem and what is happening.

Comment: You have NO server installed, so instead of repair you should INSTALL a new instance

Comment: >>>Note that the SQL server engine can connect to other servers successfully<<< Once again, you have NO SQL server engine. All you have is SSMS, and the correct phrase should be "Note that **SSMS** can connect to other servers successfully"

Comment: Okay i will try to install SQL server engine again

Comment: I think this statement is very telling *"MS SQL Server v 17.3"* There is no "version 3" of SQL Server 2017. SQL Server 2017 is version 14 (I have version 14.0.3045.24 installed) and it doesn't have Service packs, it has CU's. So the latest version of SQL Server 2017 is 2017 CU12. 17.3 would be a long way in the future. i very much suspect that the version they are quoting is their SSMS version.

Comment: uninstall completely and Install Server again.